# How to pass two parameter to reportviewer in c# using winform

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services

how to pass two parameter to reportviewer by the following method.

```
ADMSDataSetTableAdapters.pwl_detailsTableAdapter  adapter = new ADMSDataSetTableAdapters.pwl_detailsTableAdapter();
            ADMSDataSet.pwl_detailsDataTable  table = new ADMSDataSet.pwl_detailsDataTable();
           adapter.FillByCity(table,textbox1.text);
            ReportDataSource MyNewDataSouce = new ReportDataSource("Warehouse_DataSet", (DataTable)table);
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(MyNewDataSouce);
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

plz, Anyone Can help me

Answer (score 2):

Create the parameters like:

```
List<ReportParameter> list = new List<ReportParameter>();
ReportParameter param = new ReportParameter("name","value"));
list.Add(param);

this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(list);
```